# Robolectric Unsupported class file major version 59

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, robolectric

After updating my `Robolectric` version, I got the following compilation issue

> Caused by:
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed
> to transform bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar
> (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) to match attributes
> {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library,
> org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release,
> org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file
> major version 59

**Build gradle dep.**

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.6.1"
```

The previous version was 4.5.1.

The similar issue have already opened an marked as resolved. See [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5931)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/8264#issuecomment-863015607